# textbox id of user control in external java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

i am making a user control dynamically.

```
var controlMarkup = string.Empty;
Page page = new Page();
var customControl = page.LoadControl(control) as UserControl;
if (customControl != null)
{
    var htmlForm = new HtmlForm(); 
    var output = new StringWriter();
    //output.Write("<div id = 'ControlName'>" + customControl + "</div>");
    htmlForm.Controls.Add(customControl);
    page.Controls.Add(htmlForm);
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, output, false);
    controlMarkup = output.ToString();
}
return controlMarkup;
```

nut now i want to get the textbox id of user control in external javascript can anyone help me to get the id of control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution of this Problem i just use the javascriptserializer to get the client id's of the dynamic control its very good approach because RegisterCLientScript is a methos which write the string from JavaScript Serializer on the page then u can easily get ur desired ID,s of the dynamic Control

Answer (score 2):

Try this `$get("<%=lblDistance.ClientID%>")`

Comment: What do you mean by 'external'? You can't use this in .js files!

Answer (score 1):

The client-side ID can be found in the `ClientID` property.  For example, you can hide a control called `txtDistance` using jQuery in the `.aspx` page like:

```
$('#<%= lblDistance.ClientID %>').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  .net 4.0 add **ClientIDMode="Static"** to your control.

Something like:

```
 yourControlname.Attributes.Add("ClientIDMode", "Static");
```

For previous version of .net, because you are using external javascript you have two options

1. Use hidden input to store clientId's
2. View HTML produced by your page and use those Id's in your external javascripts